# Missing socket for connection to Cloud SQL from Google App Engine standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect a Python 3.7 GAE app in standard environment to a Cloud SQL Postgres 9.6 database.
The procedure is described in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-sql).

Unfortunately, the UNIX socket `/cloudsql/<DB_CONNECTION_NAME>` that is normally used to connect to the database does not exist on the GAE instance (folder `/cloudsql` is empty).

More information on what I tried:

- the GAE app and the cloud SQL instance are in the same project and region (I tried in `europe-west1` and `europe-west3`)
- I have added and removed a `beta_settings` -> `cloud_sql_instances` key in the `app.yaml` config file, to no avail. From what I understood, this should only be needed in the flexible environment anyway
- I have activated the Cloud SQL Admin UI

Has anyone encountered and solved this problem?

The SO questions about this problem are either old, unanswered, or do not solve the problem in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get the connection working with the following configuration:

```
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]]
REGION=europe-west3
INSTANCE=instance-01
```

and:

```py
import os

from flask import Flask

import psycopg2

db_user = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME')
db_pass = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD')
db_name = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE')
db_conn = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE')

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    host = '/cloudsql/{}'.format(db_conn)

    cnx = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname=db_name,
        user=db_user,
        password=db_pass,
        host=host
    )
    with cnx.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT NOW() as now;')
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    current_time = result[0][0]
    cnx.commit()
    cnx.close()

    return str(current_time)
```

and:

```
flask==1.0.2
psycopg2==2.8
```

and, with `${VARIABLE}` replaced with value:

```
runtime: python37
env_variables:
  CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE: "${PROJECT}:${REGION}:${INSTANCE}"
  CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME: ${USERNAME}
  CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD: ${PASSWORD}
  CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE}
```

Comment: are you able to see the unix socket file located at `/cloudsql/{instance_name}` in the cloud console terminal?

Comment: Also after you added the instaces in the `app.yaml`, did you have to do anything else before deploying the app?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a similar issue, the most probable root cause is detailed here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/117804657#comment16

Other possible causes, per the discussion, could be:

- A lack of public IP on the SQL instance
- Specification of the port in the configuration settings

Here are some recommendations:

- Run the application locally to make sure it works before deploying to App Engine.
- Double check the Cloud SQL configuration (e.g. username, password, instance connection name) on the app.yaml file.
- Make sure the Google Cloud SQL API is enabled.
- Try recreating the Cloud SQL instance.

Simply recreating the Cloud SQL instance or database has worked in other cases, as modifications to the quickstart’s default setup might be difficult to track.

Cheers

Comment: Why public IP is required? I struggle to understand why do we need an IP settings at all if we are using file sockets? Is this some underlying GCP infrastructure setup requirements? Can't it work with private IP?

Comment: "Specification of the port in the configuration settings". Yep, spent hours overlooking this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by enabling the Cloud SQL Admin API.

See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/debugging-connectivity